# VSCode Language Client extension - how does client receive message from the server (in 2024)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I want to write a VSCode extension that receives response from the LSP server. From the client to the server was easy. You only need to call `client.sendRequest`. It's also easy to use built-in methods. The backend will help you handle everything. However, it seems hard to send a custom method response from the server to the client. After some Googling, [this 5-year-old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041337/vscode-language-client-extension-how-to-send-a-message-from-the-server-to-the) seems to be what I need. However, the code in the link doesn't work anymore. I can't even find the method `client.onReady()`. How do I receive response in the 2024 way?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. You just need to do

```js
let response = await client.sendRequest()
```

The type of `response` is likely `unknown`, so you have to cast it yourself.